# Update outside loop

Tags: c#, datatable, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, parallel.for

I have location of various csv files in `strFilePath` array (almost 1000 files which have 1 million records in each file). It takes a lot of time to read from files and merge all the data to single datatable. So I decided to go forward with Parallel processing.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
DataTable dtMerge=new DataTable();
for(int i=0;i<strFilePath.Count;i++)
{
     Parallel.For(0, 3,m =>
     {
         clsNewClass objCls=new clsNewClass();
         DataTable dt=objCls.ReadCSV(strFilePath[m+i]);
     });
     m+=3;
}
```

The question is, how can I merge all the data from datatable `dt` to a global datatable `dtMerge` or can include all the results to a global variable `dtMerge`?

**EXPECTED CODE TO WORK**

```
DataTable dtMerge=new DataTable();
for(int i=0;i<strFilePath.Count;i++)
{
     Parallel.For(0, 3,m =>
     {
         clsNewClass objCls=new clsNewClass();
         // Is it possible like the below?
         dtMerge = objCls.ReadCSV(strFilePath[m+i]);
     });
     m+=3;
}
```

Comment: You have quite a few errors in your existing code. `m` is not declared at `m+=3` is the first that jumps out at me. Actually you may be much better off doing `Parallel.ForEach(strFilePath, filepath => { ... })`

Comment: After all how would I merge it? Is there any way without using lock(object) inside Parallel.Foreach? @Scott Chamberlain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the overload of `Parallel.For` (or `ForEach`) that gives you a local initializer and finally for the threads so you can merge your progress intra-thread without using locks. You can then [merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk78t63(v=vs.110).aspx) your intra thread tables in the finally block in to your outside table using a lock for thread safety.

```
DataTable dtMerge = new DataTable();

Parallel.ForEach(strFilePath,
     () => new DataTable(),
     (filePath, loopState, local) =>
     {
         clsNewClass objCls=new clsNewClass();
         // Is it possible like the below?
         var dt = objCls.ReadCSV(filePath);
         local.Merge(dt, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
         return local;
     },
     (local) =>
     {
         lock(dtMerge)
         {
             dtMerge.Merge(local, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);
         }
     });
```

I also got rid of your outer for loop, and replaced your inner loop with a parallel foreach there was no reason to nest your loops like that, just use a `ForEach`

Comment: I have a doubt. Would this lock actually reflects the performance of **Parallel.ForEach** ? Actually **lock** make sure that only 1 object can access at a time. Right???

Comment: The lock only happens when a worker thread is disposed so it happens very infrequently. The `local.Merge` is the one that will happen a lot and does not have a lock (nor need one because the table you are merging in to is a thread local object)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious time and answer :) @Scott Chamberlain